# Question about the metric signature of the hyperboloid model

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Previously, Wikipedia has this to say about the [Hyperboloid Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hyperboloid_model&oldid=1070297905):

> If (*x*<sub>0</sub>, *x*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *x*<sub>*n*</sub>) is a vector in the (*n* + 1)-dimensional coordinate space **R**<sup>*n*+1</sup>, the **Minkowski quadratic form** is defined to be
>
> $Q(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_0^2 - x_1^2 - \ldots - x_n^2.$
>
> The vectors *v* ∈ **R**<sup>*n*+1</sup> such that *Q*(*v*) = 1 form an *n*-dimensional hyperboloid *S* (trimmed)...
>
> The **Minkowski bilinear form** *B* is the polarization of the Minkowski quadratic form *Q* (trimmed), Explicitly,
>
> $B((x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n), (y_0, y_1, \ldots, y_n)) = x_0y_0 - x_1 y_1 - \ldots - x_n y_n .$
>
> The **hyperbolic distance** between two points *u* and *v* of *S*<sup>+</sup> is given by the formula
>
> $d(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}) = \operatorname{arcosh}(B(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}))$

I feel this strongly implies that the metric tensor is $B$, with signature (+,-,-,...). However, if we consider the example point (1,0,0,0) in **H**<sup>3</sup>, its tangent space will spanned by {(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)}, and when we apply the quadratic form to these basis vectors the result for all of them is -1.

Indeed, rather than being positive-definite, the tangent space is *negative*-definite, and this extends to the entire manifold.

It seems like the proper metric is the one with signature (-,+,+,...), which will then be positive-definite and yield a Riemannian space. Am I missing something here?

Edit: I found a tacit admission that the signature is backwards in the section on reflections:

> For two points $\mathbf p, \mathbf q \in \mathbb{H}^n, \mathbf p \neq \mathbf q$, there is a unique reflection exchanging them.
>
> Let $\mathbf u = \frac {\mathbf p - \mathbf q}{\sqrt{-Q(\mathbf p - \mathbf q)}}$.

If you have to throw in a negative to make your norm work, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Remember: Anybody can edit Wikipedia articles, do not assume that everything there is written by competent people.

Comment: I think the person who wrote it was more familiar with Minkowski space, where IIUC the choice of signature is a more arbitrary convention. The upside is that anyone (even less-than-competent people) can fix things on Wikipedia, too. :) But it'll take a careful and thorough edit to reverse the signature without breaking the article.